# using count on when creating a view

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

im have a view that need to include the count of members volunteering for an event. I'm getting an error 'not a single-group group functions'. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
CREATE VIEW atbyrd.events__view AS
SELECT e.name, e."DATE", b."LIMIT",b.allocated_amount, COUNT(em.member_id), e.comments
FROM events e INNER JOIN budgets b ON b.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN event_members em ON em.event_id  = e.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.name, 
       e."DATE", 
       b."LIMIT",
       b.allocated_amount, 
       (select COUNT(member_id) from event_members) as mem_count, 
       e.comments
FROM events e
INNER JOIN budgets b ON b.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN event_members em ON em.event_id  = e.id;
```

Comment: This counts all members not just those for a given event

Comment: I modified your answer to filter. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [analytic function `count()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions039.htm#SQLRF00624)

```
SELECT e.name
     , e."DATE"
     , b."LIMIT"
     , b.allocated_amount
     , COUNT(em.member_id) over ( partition by em.event_id )
     , e.comments
  FROM events e 
 INNER JOIN budgets b 
    ON b.event_id = e.id
 INNER JOIN event_members em 
    ON em.event_id  = e.id;
```

Simply put this counts the number of members per `event_id` but as it's not an aggregate function no GROUP BY is required. You receive the same value per `event_id`.